# How to have a playground for objective c as well . I tried obj-c runtime, chisel and Krzysztof Zabłocki

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I want to run my code of objective c just like swift. I tried Krzysztof Zabłocki KZPlayground . I am not able to get the changes I made in the runtime. I understand, I am facing runtime installation issues. Can any one let me know how to install the runtime, this framework is talking about. I am doing just this video directs me, but I am failing to see the live changes. It tells me to make objects and put it in the code KZPShow(obj) of obj. I don't see any changes reflecting in my device. What am I possibly missing?

Comment: I installed KZPlayground and tried the installation from the terminal . "  Now you can use DYCI from the Xcode :P

DYCI was successfully installed!
Use (^X) hot key in your IDE to perform code injections. Have fun.

Comment: But I don't see any injection button in Xcode in the Product tab. Any help?